# Tcl pass args "as is" to proc

Tags: list, tcl, proc, args

I want to send the command

```
exp_send -i $sid -- "yes\r"
```

to a function that will exec the command and check errors as well.
should be :

```
catch {exp_send -i $sid -- "yes\r"}
```

where :

```
[catch {$cmd [join $args]}
```

what wrong in this code :

```tcl
package require Expect

proc ErrorDetector {cmd args} {

    global res

    if { [catch {$cmd [join $args]} results] } {
       puts "Connection Could not open for exp_send\n $results"
       return -level 0 0
     }

    puts sion.
}


global spawn_id
set sid [spawn cmd.exe]
exp_send {ssh root@10.64.88.240}


ErrorDetector exp_send -i $sid -- "yes\r"
```

the comamnd:

```
$cmd [join $args]
```

is not running as:

```
$cmd [join $args]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a recent enough version of Tcl behind Expect, you can do:

```
$cmd {*}$args
```

Otherwise, with older versions of Tcl (8.4 and before) the right way to do it is one of these:

```
eval [list $cmd] $args
# Paranoid version: eval [list $cmd] [lrange $args 0 end]
```

```
eval [linsert $args 0 $cmd]
```

All the above will precisely preserve the words that you gave as arguments to your procedure. Things with `join` will *not*; that command is particularly for creating things like *human-readable* lists of things and for working with old-style “database” records such as you'd find in a Unix password database.